# Error occurred while loading Experience Profile

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-api, experience-profile

I am facing an issue where the error is occurring while loading the `Experience Profile`.

I am working on `Sitecore 9.0.2 version`.

Error is shown as below:-
[image]

When I hit the Sitecore API URL as shown in the console, I found the below error:-

[image]

Below is the Sitecore logs for reference

```
26452 15:16:16 ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP POST
URL https://mysite.local/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/search?&pageSize=20&pageNumber=1&sort=visitCount desc&Match=*&FromDate=15%2F05%2F2019&ToDate=14%2F06%2F2019

Exception System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Endpoint.Plumbing.NegotiateLanguageFilter.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting processing data in reports? make sure XConnect is working fine and reporting/processing is working good.

Comment: I had this issue yesterday, couldn't resolve it and just cleared my xDB and started over. I think if you rebuild your reporting DB, you might solve it. There seems to be a bad piece of data in the xDB database.

Comment: This is Xconnect certificate issue. check of your root have duplicate certificates

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat What do you mean by processing data in reports? Is it is data in Experience analytics then I am getting  data in Experience analytics like visits, bounce rates etc. And how to check xConnect is working fine or not. When i hit the xConnect Ur in browser it give me something like this **1:12:23:09.6006348**.

Comment: @ChrisAuer What do you mean by "cleared my xDB".

Comment: @Rajasekar I have checked root of certificates, there is no duplicate certificate.

Comment: Could you check logs in "xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data\Logs\" ? They should contain more detailed error message

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this issue. Planning on writing a blog for this. But here is the shorter version.

On CM, the error you see is not super helpful. But, as others mentioned, it is related to the certificate. In my case, the problem is due to the SolrCloud certificate. I have used self-signed for our requirement.

The issue originates from Xconnect-search (if you are using XP0, all XConnect roles will be in the same app, unlike in scaled where you can deploy Xconnect-search as a separate app). Assuming you are using a self-signed certificate for Solr (it is mandatory to run Solr in https mode with SSL certificate), we need to allow that Thumbprint in XConnect search.

In my case, though I entered it in `App_Data/jobs/continuous/IndexWorker/App_data/config/sitecore/CollectionSearch/sc.Xdb.Collection.WebClient.SOLR.xml` I still kept receiving this error.

```xml
<Sitecore>
    <XConnect>
      <CollectionSearch>
        <Services>
            <ISolrWebClientFactory>
                <Type>Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrWebClientFactory, Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr</Type>
                <As>Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.IWebClientFactory, Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr</As>
                <LifeTime>Singleton</LifeTime>
                <Options>
                   <AcceptCertificates>
                     <thumbprint1>‎69 3b 2x xx xx xx xx 4e 3a 4d fc 2e 9e 2d 92 8c c7 af 5b 6a</thumbprint1>
                     <SolrCloud>693B2XXXXXXXXXXXX4E3A4DFC2E9E2D928CC7AF5B6A</SolrCloud>                  
                   </AcceptCertificates>
                </Options>
            </ISolrWebClientFactory>
        </Services>
      </CollectionSearch>
    </XConnect>
  </Sitecore>
```

So, I ended up duplicating the thumbprints in `App_Data/Config/Sitecore/CollectionSearch/sc.Xdb.Collection.WebClient.SOLR.xml` also. And this resolved the issue.

After spending some time trying to understand how XConnect is loading the XML configuration files, it is still a puzzle to crack why I need to add the thumbprint outside of `indexingworker` job.

Hope this will help others resolve this issue. By the way, this problem occurs in 9.1 update 1 also.